# How to pass dynamic props through <router-view>

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have an app in vue and registered the router, All i need is to pass dynamic props to some components through .

app.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view :user="userVariable"></router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

router.js

```
Vue.use(Router);
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login,
      props: true,
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'profile',
      component: Profile,
      props: true,
    },
  ],
});
```

I got the props while initiating the component, but cant able get the updated props while updating the value which is `userVariable`. :(

Comment: Wanted to confirm something regarding the question, are you not able to get the updated value of the object in the components? If yes, then  try watcher on the property with the property "deep" as true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created [this CodeSanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-nwtwn) in which everything seems to be working fine.

I have tried both cases, when the variable you're passing is either a **primitive** or a **non-primitive** value.